# Jade template - does not process json in curly bracket after upgrading to pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, template-engine

Why jade does not process json properly anymore after upgrading to pug?

For instance:

```
a.btn.btn-link(href="/datasets/#{dataset.index}") Show
```

Result:

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href="/datasets/#{dataset.index}">Show</a>
```

It should be:

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href="/datasets/ISIUSXSXX">Show</a>
```

Any ideas why?

**EDIT:**

I think this is it:

```
a(href=`before${link}after`)
```

I seriously don't understand why a developer  would choose pug/jade - the 'code' looks utterly ugly and unreadable! Syntaxes are confusing. Rules are not consistent! Just a rant!

Comment: If you don't like it, why are you using it?

Comment: It comes with express-generator

Comment: i am going to change it twig or ejs at some point soon!

Comment: `express-generator` also supports EJS, handlebars and hogan. Or you can take some time to learn how to change the templating language used by your app, which [isn't that hard](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: EJS is ok. But I like twig more because you can use it for PHP apps too :-)

Comment: Or maybe react could take over them soon!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax has changed to use ES6 template strings:

```
a.btn.btn-link(href="/datasets/#{dataset.index}")
```

becomes:

```
a.btn.btn-link(href=`/datasets/${dataset.index}`)
```

[Reference issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2305)

> We removed support for interpolation in attributes since it was unnecessarily complex in implementation and tended to delay users learning that they can just use any JavaScript value in place of attributes

Comment: but it returns `${dataset.index}` instead of data... :(